# How to send notification with button in react native expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, expo

I am working on app where I have some requirement , Actually I want to send notification when user click on button . I really tried but didn't find any solution . Could someone please help me how to resolve this issue .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the point of sending a notification immediately after pressing a button is, however, Expo provides a nice library `expo-notifications`:

Use `presentNotificationAsync` in order to immediately present a notification.

Use `scheduleNotificationAsync` in order to schedule a notification in the future.